# Verify if some node of xml tree is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, tree

I have a xml string.

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="cooking">
    <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
    <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>30.00</price>
  </book>
  <book category="children">
    <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
    <author>James McGovern</author>
    <author>Per Bothner</author>
    <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
    <author>James Linn</author>
    <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>49.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web" cover="paperback">
    <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

I need to validate that all the nodes have something contained (Value or more nodes).

I'm working with nodejs. I searched if there was a package that allow me to browse all the nodes, but I have not seen any, is the only solution to use recursion?

Node by node, if contains some node, I call the same function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[xmldom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom)** package which has a nice method called `hasChildNodes()` through which you can determine whether the XML document really has one.

Here is an example, (You need to modify it according to your requirement).

```
var xmlDomObj = new (require('xmldom')).DOMParser;
var xmlDocument = xmlDomObj.parseFromString(YOUR_XML_VARIABLE);

var nodeObj = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName(nodeName_you_are_looking_for)[0];   
if (nodeObj) {
    var currentNodeObj = nodeObj.childNodes[0];
    if (!currentNodeObj) { // if the node not found
        // Logic goes here if the node not found
    } else {
        // Logic goes here if the node is found
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!